# Convert string of particles into one particle openCV python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am doing a bit of image processing, and I want to be able to follow a trend in an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKUC2.png). I want to be able to link the individual particles together in that image in order to create one curve. I do have a bit of [code](http://pastebin.com/GpCZEm0J)* that I use to threshold the original [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRcwe.png).

I have tried editing the thresholds in order to get the particles to "mesh together," as a varied threshold does cause the particles to grow and thus almost bridge the gap between them.

If there is a way to detect a correlation between the particles and connect them, I would like to know. I have looked into a concept called blob detection, but I haven't been able to understand it too well.

Any help on how to tackle this problem is greatly appreciated

here's the code from that link:

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np  
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('imgs/image.jpg',0)
#img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)

ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(img,117,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

titles = ['Original Image', 'Global Thresholding (v = 127)']
images = [img, th1]

for i in xrange(2):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()

cv2.imwrite("test_thresh2.png", th1)
```

Comment: Givew an example of the image. Your definition of "particle" is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Take look on OpenCV [Eroding and Dilating](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) where you can use Dilating.

See the example.

```
  Mat src=imread("src.png",1);
  int dilation_size = 3;
  Mat element = getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT,
                                      Size( 2*dilation_size + 1, 2*dilation_size+1 ),
                                      Point( dilation_size, dilation_size ) );

  Mat dst;
  dilate( src, dst, element );
  imshow("dst",dst);
```

[image]             [image]